# Sql server AOAG license on readable secondary

Tags: sql-server

Scenario:
Microsoft sql server AlwasOn Availabiliry Group:

For SQL server License on readable secondary if :
Example
Primary server  cores : 32
Secondary Replica cores : 32, but at the time it's secondary only 12 cores assigned to sql server.
The question:
Will the license be calculated for the 32, or the 12 cores on active readable secondary

Comment: Thank you , I supposed I could try one of both , through affinity , or assigned vCPU using vmware.

Comment: You know enterprise license is very expensive., I measured CPU usage and it was as stated needed 32 cores on primary and only 8 on secondary , but I need to make use of using secondary for HA, so I thought to assign less cores when it is used only for reporting , and create automatic job to increase affinity if failover occured

Comment: Using processor affinity to reduce processor usage *DOES NOT* reduce your licensing burden. You must license all cores present, whether you're using them or not. You may wish to consult a licensing vendor/partner to ensure you're licensing the product properly.

Comment: What do you mean by `but at the time it's secondary only 12 cores assigned to sql server.` ? Can you explain

Answer (score 2):

You have to cover the readable secondary with proper license. So you have to count the cores on the secondary.

Count the cores assigned by the virtualizer (private cloud) or physical total cores (on-premise install).